# How to convert a 2d array to a 2d string in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

The problem is quite simple.
I would like to convert a 2d array to a string and preserve the brackets. How can I do that? The String() method will remove all the brackets, unfortunately.

Example:
`[[21, 21], [19, -2]]` should be converted to
`"[[21, 21], [19, -2]]"`

Do I need to build a for-loop to do that or is there built-in method or something similar I can use?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(yourArray)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
let a = [[21, 21], [19, -2]] ;

console.log( JSON.stringify(a) );
```